# How to manipulate $8^{k+1}-3^{k+1} = 8(8^k)-3(3^k)$ to become $(8^k-3^k)8+5(3^k)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$8^{k+1}-3^{k+1} = 8(8^k)-3(3^k)\tag{law of exponents}$$
$$= (8^k-3^k)8+5(3^k)\tag{manipulate}$$

I need tips on how to manipulate it to reach the second expression.

Thanks

Comment: $5-8=-3$? Just multiply the expression out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$8^{k+1}-3^{k+1} = 8(8^k)-3(3^k) =8(8^k) - (3^k)(8-5)= 8(8^k)-8(3^k)+5(3^k)\\ =8(8^k - 3^k)+ 5(3^k) $$

Comment: Many thanks for detailed steps, I am learning and math was always difficult for me

Comment: @JorgeeFG, you're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$(8^k - 3^k)8 + 5(3^k) = 8^{k + 1} - 8(3^k) + 5(3^k)$$
$$ = 8^{k+1} - (3^k)(8 - 5) = 8^{k+1} - 3^{k+1}$$

Comment: The L.H.S of the last step should be (-8+5) instead of (8-3).